# How to linearize a constraint including product of two binary variables in summation with different indexes?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, linearization

I am trying to linearize the following two expressions:

$\sum_{k=1}^K \sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{h=1}^W x_{ijkt} a_{hjt} =\sum_{k=1}^K \sum_{t=1}^T  x_{ijkt} k , i\in N, j \in M$

$\sum_{k=1}^K \sum_{t=p_{ijk}}^T\sum_{l=t-P_{ijk}+1}^t x_{ijkt} a_{hjl} =\sum_{k=1}^K \sum_{t=p_{ijk}}^T  x_{ijkt} a_{hjt} p_{ijk} , i\in N, j \in M, h \in W$

$x_{ijkt}$: binary variable

$a_{hjt}$: binary variable

$p_{ijk}$: parameter

K: parameter

I already know product of two binary variables can be linearized as follows:

ab=z

$a \le z$

$b \le z$

$z\ge a+b-1$

Accordingly I did as follows to linearized the first constraint:

$x_{ijkt} a_{hjt}=z_{ijkth}$

$i \in N, j \in M, k \in K, t \in T, h \in w, x_{ijkt} \le z_{ijkth}$

$i \in N, j \in M, k \in K, t \in T, h \in w, a_{hjt} \le z_{ijkth}$

$i \in N, j \in M, k \in K, t \in T, h \in w, x_{ijkt} + a_{hjt}-1 \ge z_{ijkth}$

And finally converted the constraint as follows:

$\sum_{k=1}^K \sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{h=1}^W z_{ijkth} =\sum_{k=1}^K \sum_{t=1}^T  x_{ijkt} k , i\in N, j \in M$

However it makes the model infeasible!

Comment: Your binary multiplication $z=ab$ is not correct. The constraints $a\le z$ and $b \le z$ should read $z \le a $ and $z \le b$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle the sum of products

$$ \sum_{i,j}  x_i y_j  $$

with $x_i, y_i \in \{0,1\}$ you need to introduce a new variable $z_{i,j}\in \{0,1\}$ and write:

$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i,j} z_{i,j}\\
&z_{i,j} \le x_i&\forall i,j\\
&z_{i,j} \le y_j&\forall i,j\\
&z_{i,j} \ge x_i+y_j-1&\forall i,j\\
& 0 \leq z_{i,j} \leq 1&\forall i,j
\end{align}
$$

Note that we can relax $z$ to be continuous (i.e., $z\in [0,1]$) as $z$ assumes integer values automatically. This formulation extends naturally to more indices.

Comment: In the last constraint the direction should be $\ge$.

Comment: @YukiJ Yes, thanks.